# Codeigniter attachment not send along with email.

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter. I am using CI 2.1.4
I am trying to attach a txt file with the email. The email go through and received in the email but without attachment.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
class email extends CI_Controller{
    function index(){
        $config = array(
            'protocol'=>'smtp',
            'smtp_host'=>'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port'=>465,
            'smtp_user'=>'xxxxxx',
            'smtp_pass'=>'xxxxxx'
        );

        $this->load->library('email',$config);

        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->to('xxxxx@gmail.com');
        $this->email->from('xxxxxx', 'xxxxx');
        $this->email->subject('This is email subject');
        $this->email->message('This is email message body');

        $this->email->attach('attachments/file.txt');

            if($this->email->send()){
                echo("Email successfully send");
            } else{
                $this->email->print_debugger();
            } 
    }
}
```

?>

file.txt is the file placed i the attachments folder and attachment folder is at root directory.

URL,HTML helper is loaded in autoload.php.

any help ???

Answer (score 1):

try like this 
it should be problem of your path

```
$path = <?php base_url(); ?>.'attachments/file.txt';
$this->email->attach($path);
```

Comment: <?= `__DIR__` ?>'/attachments/file.txt';

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it like below,

```
$this->email->attach(FCPATH. '\dist\pdf\\' . $filename);
```

In my case "/" didn't work. **FCPATH** is to get the absolute path which is a must. hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Makes sure you are using a file path for your attachment and not a URL.

`/path/to/file/on/server/file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

attachment folder should be in the same location of application folder

like
Project Name
|
|
-Application
- your uploading folder

```
   $file =  './attachments/Info.txt';

   $this->email->attach($file);
```